# Stored data not displayed correctly

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have SQL DB with table where the stored data will be encrypted if i choose the query in the program.

If i look directly in the DB there is a string wich make no sense i.e phone.

[image]

Is there a way to see the correct data in the Table?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That looks like Base64 encoded data, you likely need to Base64 decode to get a binary buffer then decrypt that.  If thats the case its not a great way to store encrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below example and extend it further per your need,

```
    DECLARE @source VARBINARY(max)
        ,@encoded VARCHAR(max)
        ,@decoded VARBINARY(max)

    SET @source = convert(VARBINARY(max), 'ForBase64')
    SET @encoded = cast('' AS 
     XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)')

    SET @decoded = cast('' AS 
     XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@encoded"))', 'varbinary(max)')

    SELECT convert(VARCHAR(max), @source) AS source_varchar
        ,@source AS source_binary
        ,@encoded AS encoded
        ,@decoded AS decoded_binary
        ,convert(VARCHAR(max), @decoded) AS decoded_varchar
```

The output is,

```
source_varchar  source_binary           encoded         decoded_binary          decoded_varchar
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ForBase64       0x466F72426173653634    Rm9yQmFzZTY0    0x466F72426173653634    ForBase64
```